# Adding Icons on TabBottomNavigation React Native

Tags: react-native

I have This navigation, how can I add Icons on the bottomTabNavigator

```
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
      mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
        Home: createStackNavigator({
          Search: SearchScreen,
          Results: ResultsShowScreen
        }),
        Map: AccountScreen,
        Scanner: AccountScreen,
        Account: AccountScreen
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can add icons to tabs using defaultNavigationOptions, here is an example,
more information about tabs can be got from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/4.x/tab-based-navigation.html

````
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let IconComponent = Ionicons;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = focused
            ? 'ios-information-circle'
            : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
          // Sometimes we want to add badges to some icons.
          // You can check the implementation below.
          IconComponent = HomeIconWithBadge;
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list';
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here!
        return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
);```
````